# Is it true that if $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, limits-without-lhopital

And if so, what theorems/results leads to this conclusion. I have been searching like crazy but I don't know what to look for, I have a vague memory of this result and I am roughly 97% that it is correct.

Comment: This is equivalent to the first part of the Fundamental theorem of calculus: $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(x) dx = f(t).$ If you need to prove the first part of the FTC then this is commonly done using the mean value theorem

Comment: Hint: Remember the limit definition of the derivative and combine that with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: What you've written down is exactly the derivative of the function $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$.

Comment: Also note that $\int_a^b = \int_a^c + \int_c^b = \int_c^b  - \int_c^a$.

Comment: Replace $f(x)$ by $\lim_{h\to0}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(x)dt$ and bring it to the other side. We need to prove that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)]dt=0$. We can use triangle inequality $|h|^{-1}|\int_{x}^{x+h}[f(t)-f(x)]dt|\leq |h|^{-1}\max_{t\in[x,x+h]}|f(t)-f(x)||h|=\max_{t\in[x,x+h]}|f(t)-f(x)|$. Now the continuity gives you that for any $\epsilon>0$ you can fix $\delta>0$ such that if $|h|<\delta$ then $\max_{t\in[x,x+h]}|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: So, the main theorems to use are the [integral's triangle inequality](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality_for_Integrals) and well, the additivity of the integral and definition of limits.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! It was exactly what I was looking for. It has been a long time ago since I did the introductory course in calculus, didn't even occur to me to check there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to invke the FTC for this. Note that, by the monotonicity of the integral, $$h\min_{x\le s\le x+h}f(s) 
=  \int_x^{x+h} \min_{x\le s\le x+h}f(s)\,dt
\le \int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt$$
Similarly,
$$h\max_{x\le s\le x+h}f(s) 
= \int_x^{x+h}\max_{x\le s\le x+h}f(s)\,dt
\ge \int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt$$
Now divide these inequalities by $h$ and let $h\rightarrow 0$. By continuity,
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \min_{x\le s\le x+h}f(s) = f(x)$$ with a similar result for the $\max$. Combinining the resulting inequalities yields the result.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is continuous, the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable with derivative $F'(x) = f(x)$. Notice that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt}{h}  = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_a^{x+h}f(t)dt - \int_a^x f(t)dt}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h}$$
and use the definition of the derivative.

It has been pointed out by Stephen Donovan that perhaps this problem arose in proving the fundamental theorem of calculus. In that case, the comments on the original post detail some methods of solution.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that OP may have come across their problem while attempting to prove the FTC, in which case this would be a circular argument since it relies on the FTC.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you, I'll edit my answer with a remark.